# PHP error - Unknown column 'first_name' in 'field list'

Tags: php, mysql

I am showing a student how to connect a form on html to a MySQL database (we use xampp, apache, MySQL)

The student is using the same html and php code as my website, my website receives the data to my database perfectly when the xampp server is turned on at my pc. However when the student follows the same steps and I fill in his form at his URL we receive this error:

Warning: Undefined variable $sql in D:\user157\My Documents\ict\Assignment\startbootstrapneedsfixing\details_entry.php on line 38
error: Unknown column 'first_name' in 'field list'

I have checked their database creation to receive the information and everything matches neatly.

Any ideas on what we could try to get the connection working? Can provide more information if you want more information.

(The only part this is different is that I use the default htdocs folder to work on my website, where as the student does not have access to C Drive due to school regulations and had to update their apache root file location to D Drive. Could this effecting the connection in someway? Or is this simply a matter of defining the variables to "" first. If so why do I not need to do that)

Thank you for helping if you have time, many thanks.

```
<?php
$server_name="localhost";
$username="root";
$password="";
$database_name="database123";



$conn=mysqli_connect($server_name,$username,$password,$database_name);
//now check the connection_aborted
if(!$conn)
{
        die("Connection Failed:" . mysqli_connect_error());
}




if(isset($_POST['save']))
{
        $first_name = $_POST['first_name'];
        $last_name = $_POST['last_name'];
        $gender = $_POST['gender'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $phone = $_POST['phone'];
        
//For inserting the values to mysql database_name
        $sql_query = "INSERT INTO entry_details 
(first_name,last_name,gender,email,phone)
        VALUES ('$first_name','$last_name','$gender','$email','$phone')";

    if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql_query))
{
        echo "new Details Entry inserted successfully !";
}
    else 
{
        echo "error: " . $sql . "" . mysqli_error($conn);
}
    mysqli_close($conn);
}
?>
```

Comment: Can the user confirm that the database table `entry_details` has the correct table columns, could just be a typo in the schema

Comment: Also......... Your script is open to [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174). Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187) You should always use [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) in either the `MYSQLI_` or `PDO` API's instead of concatenating user provided values into the query. Never trust ANY user input!

Comment: please check your database field.

Comment: Your undefined variable message is coming from the error message where `$sql` is used but never initialised. The rest of the message is clear: there's no `first_name` column in the table. Check the schema for typos.

Comment: @TheLovelySausage Yes I said in the original post I have checked the database123 twice everything is matching

AlivetoDie it's just for a school project but I will look into this in the future. 

Switi Yeah it is checked. 

TangentiallyPerpendicular Database123 has entry_details and first_name

Comment: The exact code works on my computer but not on the students. It's something else

Comment: OK OK I really appreciate everyone helping me out. And you were all right. I asked him to just remake database123 and be very careful with the fields etc. And what do you know it worked. When we checked the columns 3 times they were perfectly matched. Anyway we were all super happy it's working. Thanks again everyone.